# Using Javascript slice inside angular expression

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I receive a number representing a date in ddmmyy format eg.: 250615 i need transform into this format : 25/06/15.

I canot use the angular date filter because i receive a number.

I try to use slice in this way but only print the first number

{{ singularitem.Dia.slice(0,2)}} {{ singularitem.Dia.slice(2,2) }} {{ singularitem.Dia.slice(-2,2) }}

How can it be done ?

Thank´s in advance

Comment: better should formatted from server side

Comment: in my case is not an option, sure would be the best option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use the `date` filter, just create your own filter, doing whatever you want it to do:

```
app.filter('transformDate', function() {
  return function(date) {
    // Split string at every second character and combine them again with a `/` in between
    return date.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('/');
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
{{date | transformDate}}
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/uBeT0eHOoAlHDUWydOpM?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Numyx work´s fine to me !  is the first time i create and angularjs filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a vanilla javascript function. If your format is always dd/mm/yy check this function:

```
(function () {
    var date = "250615";
    date = date.slice(0, 2) + "/" + date.slice(2,4) + "/" + date.slice(4,6);
    console.log(date);
})()
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d7kx3aeq/)**

Comment: var date = 250615 +""    Since he receives a number

Comment: @SridharChidurala Yes or `toString()`

Answer (score 1):

Slice is a prototype function of Strings and Arrays, not numbers. You need to convert your number to string first.

If you want to convert that number to a date object, you'd need:

```
function parseDate(dateAsNumber) {
  var dateAsString = "" + dateAsNumber;
  var day = Number(dateAsString.substr(0, 2));
  //months are index 0
  var month = Number(dateAsString.substr(2,2)) - 1; 
  //assumming all dates are 2000+ since you only get 2 digits
  var year = Number(dateAsString.substr(4,2)) + 2000; 

  var date = new Date(year, month, day);
  return date;
}
```

Calling parseDate(250615) returns Thu Jun 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Comment: Thank you Yves, helps me a lot.